# xcode localization export xmllint faillure

Tags: ios, xcode, xmllint

I have a strange problem in my xcode project. When i want to import or export a localization xcode gives the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/xmllint exited with status 1
```

Some research tells me that status 1 means `Unclassified` but i cannot find what that means and where i should look for the answer.

I have tried to do this on 2 other macs but all show the same error. Somehow it looks like it cannot parse my project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I faced the similar issue. Please check my answer below, might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struggled with the same problem for 2 days.
Finally I decided to export localization using terminal. Here's the code to export using terminal

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <dirpath> -project <projectname> [[-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>]]
```

1. go to the path where you are having the Project, in dirpath again give the path of the Project and in **projectname** give your project name including extension. Please remove <> too.Replace [[-exportLanguage targetlanguage]] with **-exportLanguage fr** , Since I wanted french language , I used **fr**.

just hit the enter. Terminal also gave me the same error **/usr/bin/xmllint exited with status 1**

But Unlike Xcode, terminal gave some extra Information. It told me the Places where there was parsing Problem. Like in my case I named some button "CC " i.e. CC and Three space. I removed the space and again tried to Export localization via XCODE and finally got SUCCESS.

PS: Exporting localization via terminal doesn't gurantee 100% success, but atleast it told me the places where there was issue.

To learn move about Localization 
 [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I managed to resolve it. In my case, the xliff file did output, but it was improperly formatted around a certain area of text from one of my UI elements. This was my starting point.

After removing the text that was entered there and re-exporting, the error code went away. My guess was that there was some improper character-encoding for something in the string that made xmllint throw an error.

I realize that this is vague response, but it is tough to track down the source of this problem. I would say that looking for areas in your project where text is being output and looking for areas where you may have copy-pasted in text instead of typing it. I'm sure that there are other ways for this error to be thrown, but this was my solution. I hope it helps :)